# PrintWriter not having expected output

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to create a program that sorts input from files into lines where Strings that contain the same characters are joined together in the same line but separated by commas.
To do this I've implemented a HashMap class that contains a HashNode class, hash table, dispertion function, etc...

Example:

Input:

may dog bat god

yam cat

act tab amy

Expected Output:

[cat, act]

[bat, tab]

[dog, god]

[may, yam, amy]

Actual Output:

act,
act,
act,
act,
act,
act,
act,
act,
act,
god,
god,
god,
god,
god,
god,
god,
god,
god,
amy,
amy,
amy,
amy,
amy,
amy,
amy,
amy,
amy,
tab,
tab,
tab,
tab,
tab,
tab,
tab,
tab,
tab,
,
,

I've been solving a couple of issues in the AEDHashMapAED class and I don't think there is anything wrong there so I think the issue is in the way the input is read/ written out, but I'm not sure where.
Leaving below the code for the class, grouping program and interface and a couple of functions that the class implements. Help is appreciated!
EDIT: After debugging for a while longer I've narrowed the issue to the printwriter since the list is properly populated, but when I try to output each element the way I have, it iterates 7 or 8 times through each list element and prints that element instead of iterating 1 time through the list elements and printing the elements that are the same.

HashMap Class:

```
package serie2.mapCollections
class AEDHashMapAED<K, V> : AEDMutableMap<K, V> {
     class AEDHashNode<K, V>: AEDMutableMap.MutableEntry<K, V> {
         constructor(k: K, v: V){
             key = k
             value = v
         }
         override var value: V
         override val key: K
         var next: AEDHashNode<K, V>? = null
         var previous: AEDHashNode<K, V>? = null
         override fun setValue(newValue: V): V {
            value = newValue
            return value
        }
    }
    override var size: Int=0
        private set
    private lateinit var table: Array<AEDHashNode<K, V>?>
    private var dimTable: Int = 0

    constructor() {
        table = arrayOfNulls<AEDHashNode<K, V>?>(10)
        dimTable = 10
    }
    constructor(size: Int) {
        table = arrayOfNulls<AEDHashNode<K, V>?>(size)
        dimTable = size
    }
    private fun hashCode(k: K): Int {
        var idx = (k.hashCode() % dimTable)
        return if (idx < 0) idx + dimTable else idx
    }
    override fun put(key: K, value: V): V?{
        val pos = hashCode(key)
        var node = table[pos]
        while (node != null) {
            if(node.key == key) return node.setValue(value)
            if(node.next != null){
                node = node.next
            }

        }
            val novo = AEDHashNode(key, value)
            novo.next = table[pos]
            table[pos]?.let { tp -> tp.previous = novo }
            table[pos] = novo
            size++
            return null

    }
    override fun remove(key: K): V? {
        val pos = hashCode(key)
        var node = table[pos]
        while (node?.key != key) {
            node?.previous = node
            node = node?.next ?: return null
        }
        val oldValue = node?.value
        if (node?.previous != null) {
            node.previous!!.next = node.next
        } else {
            table[pos] = node?.next
        }
        size--
        return oldValue
    }
    private inner class MyIterator() : Iterator<AEDMutableMap.MutableEntry<K, V>> {
        var currentPos: Int = -1
        var nodeIt: AEDHashNode<K, V>? = null
        var currentValue: AEDHashNode<K, V>? = null
        override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
            if (currentValue != null) return true
            while (++currentPos < table.size) {
                if (nodeIt == null) {
                    nodeIt = table[currentPos]
                }

                if (nodeIt != null) {
                    val node = nodeIt
                    nodeIt = nodeIt!!.next

                    if (node?.value != null) {
                            currentValue = node
                            return true
                    }
                }
            }
            return false
        }

        override fun next(): AEDMutableMap.MutableEntry<K, V> {
            if(hasNext()){
                val aux = currentValue
                currentValue = null
                return aux!!
            }
            else return null!!
        }
    }
    override operator fun get(key: K): V? {
        val pos = hashCode(key)
        var node = table[pos]
        while(node != null){
            if (node.key == key) {
                return node.value
            }
            node = node.next
        }
        return null
    }
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<AEDMutableMap.MutableEntry<K, V>> {
        return MyIterator()
    }
    override fun containsKey(k:K):Boolean {
        val index = hashCode(k)
        var node = table[index]
            while (node != null) {
                if (node.key == k) {
                    return true
                }
                node = node.next
            }
        return false
    }
}
```

Grouping function:

```
package serie2

import serie2.mapCollections.AEDHashMapAED
import serie2.mapCollections.set
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime
import kotlin.time.measureTime

@ExperimentalTime
@OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
fun main(args:Array<String>){
    val wordMap = AEDHashMapAED<String, String>(1000)

    var pW = createWriter(args[0])
    var bR = createReader(args[1])
    var elapsed1: Duration = measureTime {
        bR.useLines { lines ->
            lines.forEach { line ->
                val words = line.split(" ")
                words.forEach { word ->
                    val key = word.toCharArray().sorted().toString()
                    wordMap.set(key, word)
                }
            }
        }

        pW.use { writer ->
            for(list in wordMap){
                list.key.forEach {
                    pW.println(("${list.value}, "))
                }

            }
        }
    }
    println("Tempo: $elapsed1")
}
```

Interface implemented by class

```
package serie2.mapCollections
interface AEDMutableMap<K,V>:Iterable<AEDMutableMap.MutableEntry<K, V>> {
    interface MutableEntry<K, V>{
        val key: K
        var value:V
        fun setValue(newValue: V): V
    }
    val size: Int
    fun put(key: K, value: V): V?
    fun remove(key: K): V?
    operator fun get(key: K): V?
    fun containsKey(k: K): Boolean
}
```

Extension map functions

```
package serie2.mapCollections

operator fun <K, V> AEDMutableMap<K, V>.set(key: K, value: V){
    put(key, value)
}

operator fun <K,V> AEDMutableMap<K, V>.contains(k:K):Boolean{
    return containsKey(k)
}
```